# Using data-number-to-fixed as additionalViewData on Html.EditorFor

Tags: html, model-view-controller, attributes

I want to use this properties data-number-to-fixed and data-number-stepfactor on my Html.EditorFor control but it does not allow me to do that.  Currently the Editor for looks like this

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreditCardFees, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control text-right", @step = "0.01", @type = "number" } })
```

But when I add those 2 attributes Visual Studio's Intellisense complains like such 
[image]

and when I run it will show compiler error

> Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term 'fixed'

Any ideas how do I use these 2 attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found an answer, just use _ "underscore" in replacement of the - "dashes", MVC will convert it to dashes on compile time.